# Why mapping websocket not working?

Tags: java, websocket

I have simple web socket :

```
@ServerEndpoint("/chat")
public class ChatEndpoint {

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(final Session session, final String msg) {
        try {

            cashing(session, msg);
            newsletter(session, msg);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But my view chat page `index.jsp` always mapping to root `http://localhost:8080/PsiNavigator`. when I try add to path `/chat` I get `404`. Regardless of value in annotation `@ServerEndpoint("/chat")` or `("bla-bla")` always work only root in browser:

[image]

My annotation is: `@ServerEndpoint("/chat")` on both screen.
[image]

How to change URL for browser to `http://localhost:8080/PsiNavigator/chat`?
Thank You.

Comment: It's immutable because it wouldn't make sense to be able to change it at runtime, but that's not what you're actually asking. You're asking why your present static, immutable mapping doesn't work.

Comment: @EJP no my static present is work see in first screen but chat always mapping to root. It's issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing that you have to access to your websocket endpoint using ws protocol and not http.

I recommed you to follow this helpfull tuto showing how to build a full websocket application example(backend and frontend).
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html